# How do I update specific element in array in mongodb/nodejs?

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume I have a collection (named 'items') of documents similar to this one:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("123456789"),
  antennas: [ { "port": "1", "serial": "27536" }, { "port": "2", "serial": "63409" } ]
}
```

How do I grab this document simply by _id and change an element in the 'antennas' array, that has a port number of "2", by setting it's serial to "0"? So that it looks like this...

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("123456789"),
  antennas: [ { "port": "1", "serial": "27536" }, { "port": "2", "serial": "0" } ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the positional operator `$`? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#---update-

Comment: yes, but I'm trying to grab the element by _id (not a query), so I am getting an error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.

Comment: What was the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting means that the positional operator $ did not find a matching element in the antennas array based on your query. You need to include the array field as part of the query document in order to use the positional operator. For example, if you want to update the serial of the antenna with port 2 in the document with _id 123456789, you need to specify both the _id and the antennas.port in the query document.
For example:

```
db.items.update(
  { _id: ObjectId("123456789"), "antennas.port": "2" },
  { $set: { "antennas.$.serial": "0" } }
);
```